# Dynamic hostname and port proxying with apache

Tags: apache, proxy, apache2

Is it possible to use apache to proxy a hostname and port dynamically like so:

```
/<PORT>/<HOSTNAME> -> http://<HOSTNAME>.domain.local:<PORT>
```

I've tried the using `ProxyPassMatch`:

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/([0-9]+)/(host-[0-9]+)$" "http://$2.domain.local:$1"
```

But apache throws a syntax error AH00526. This is using apache 2.4.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch):

> The URL argument must be parsable as a URL ***before*** regexp substitutions
>   (as well as after). This limits the matches you can use.

The only workaround I can think of is to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) with [[P]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^/([0-9]+)/(host-[0-9]+)$" "http://$2.domain.local:$1" [P]
```

(But this comes with performance penalty, and also keep in mind that with such dynamic proxying you can not use [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) to adjust the URL in HTTP redirect responses)